# JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager with connection mode

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

Good day. I can't beat this error.

I send xml message and the given error falls.

Is there a problem with the send configuration on my side or is it something else?

```
JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager 'QM1' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'localhost(1414)'.; nested exception is com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedIllegalStateException: JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager 'QM1' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'localhost(1414)'.
Check the queue manager is started and if running in client mode, check there is a listener running. Please see the linked exception for more information.; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2538' ('MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE').
```

Comment: As the error says `2538' ('MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE')`, this means that the MQ client was unable to connect to `localhost(1414)`, can you try a simple `telnet localhost 1414` to see if you can connect?  Also worth checking to see if you find any corresponding errors in the queue managers `AMQERR01.LOG`.

Answer (score 0):

> JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager 'QM1' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'localhost(1414)'.

> JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2538' ('MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE').

1. Do you have a queue manager called 'QM1' running locally on your PC/laptop?
2. You could try '127.0.0.1(1414)' rather than 'localhost(1414)'
3. Since your queue manager is running locally, you can connect in bindings mode.  i.e. remove the hostname, port # and channel name from your MQ connection details.
4. Did you define an MQ listener on port 1414?  And did you start it?

i.e. MQSC commands:

```
DEFINE LISTENER('LISTENER.TCP') TRPTYPE(TCP) CONTROL(QMGR) PORT(1414)
START LISTENER('LISTENER.TCP')
```